# change captcha design in Fast Secure Contact Form plugin

Tags: plugins, contact, captcha

I am using  [Fast Secure Contact Form plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-contact-form/) to create contact form widget.It working fine . Now i like to change captcha appearance.

Original captcha generated by plugin

[image: fs contact form generates captcha]

But, I need to change it design like below

[image]

Any option available or any other ways to do this !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that a image like that is very easy to read by almost any OCR. The first one is much more hard to crack.

Anyway, if you don't want to hack the existing plugin, you can use [Really Simple Captcha](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-captcha/), it looks exactly like that.

In your form:

```
<?php
 $captcha_instance = new ReallySimpleCaptcha();
 $prefix = mt_rand();
 $word = $captcha_instance->generate_random_word();
 $image = $captcha_instance->generate_image($prefix, $word);
?>

<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="captcha-id" value="<?php echo $prefix; ?>" />
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="72" height="24" />
```

after your form is submitted:

```
$captcha_instance = new ReallySimpleCaptcha(); 
if(!$captcha_instance->check($_POST['captcha_id'], $_POST['captcha'])) die('wrong captcha!');

// captcha ok, remove the image
$captcha_instance->remove($captcha_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently added reCAPTCHA feature to the forms:
By default, the original Secure Image CAPTCHA is enabled, but you can enable Google reCAPTCHA if you want. Just go to the form edit page Security tab - CAPTCHA Settings. Check the setting "Enable reCAPTCHA", enter your Google reCAPTCHA keys for the site. Included is a link to get new free keys.